# Get the type of objects in a container like Array or NullableArray

Tags: julia

Suppose I have an object which has a type like `NullableArray{Int64}` -- how do I know that the elements have type `Int64` (well, `Nullable{Int64}`) without actually accessing any element (ie, it can be done when the object is empty).  Is there a general way to figure out what `SubType` is from an object of type `Type{SubType}`?

Edit: Whoops, to expand on the accepted answer below I realized I was doing eltype(x) but needed to do eltype(eltype(x)) for the example of Nullables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`eltype`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/collections/#Base.eltype)

```
assert(eltype(collect(1:3)) == Int)
```