# How to programmatically get the inner type of a container in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, types, julia

How can I get in Julia the inner type of a container, more specifically of a DataArray ?

For example in this code:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame( a = ["a","b","c"], b = [1,2,3], d=[0.1,0.2,0.3])
typeof(df[:a])
DataArrays.DataArray{String,1}
```

I would like to retrieve `String`, and then use it for building my own data structure.

EDIT: Closing my own question as duplicate, as there is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403505/get-the-type-of-objects-in-a-container-like-array-or-nullablearray) (`eltype(df[:a])`)